# Invalid signature while signing JWT with RSA Keys using https://jwt.io/

Tags: jwt, rsa, jwk

Hi I am testing some api through POSTMAN.

1. REGISTRATION API- It takes public key and stores in server.To get public JWK Key I am using `https://mkjwk.org/`. It generates a key with public and private key. Below is the key generated:

   ```
   {
     "kty": "RSA",
     "d": "HgP6c8xA3D_-8DKgSk3fQ_FZuPj2RNSFE5NLfGz3GJjkyt9fzOPztNObQmLZ2EoJzPrYL8ljk-1mKGIr5Ma1n4TPX_kQ9JErq9wNyhMUTykQ8PqjMuxmUpddn43RZ27VPjvUvHMulk5hPBFv0uH3LnDsM1xn34icj40y4zcRTYXwixqDgj74Ua_9aaZwPXX06Ykc3vzC5M4F5JP4ZjuLTFjmM8jxzJpu4JNDncXwhHE5Xtv3t1oezXTHNZdRzyTTtFLOeyYeLt5WWM-y549du3hsUtvgNnJ4JTS4uEHEonDMW8CV5ZzoQE8F81LT5Q84coYzOjVlzC50w7st3vLFYQ",
     "e": "AQAB",
     "use": "sig",
     "kid": "sdk291",
     "alg": "RS256",
     "n": "0h5Pgw32t3NtODVj1UrNkk90RytZBz2T09JBEo1NwYtw0T7NM3SrFsleLK8e_DknE26rB8EXD2T1YmUSuseuWvW-LPdwbk--SrKo8Df1H5ff5hDZYJ_x-NPDJ_ZmoY7r2U83aGY-DubilufhDf6icB2auTGxBvVylAl5Jdf7UBsjHAWrgWAtFFvnkbcaUk1O7ZA8nS4Iyk4l8vVsoUOJCSRrysceObAOG-EYj1UfdzOBZsuSj5Usst6ebRjF9M1VNJOLcvm6EiAqazayyqbsengnA-hqUGRgfd6HXXZ5Hg4BU_srPVBXrVmx81azHY5lRUdZr_Khtw4O0Zy3UIwMWw"
   ```

   }

I am only sending public key portion to this API and this API Works fine.

2. GETTING ACCESS TOKEN USING JWT API- This takes a JWT which will be created with some claims . And we have to sign it with RSA Public and private key. I am facing problem in signing the JWT.
   To get text/pem  version of public and private keys from above JWK, I am using `https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp` . This gives us below public and private key.

   ```
       -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0h5Pgw32t3NtODVj1UrN
   kk90RytZBz2T09JBEo1NwYtw0T7NM3SrFsleLK8e/DknE26rB8EXD2T1YmUSuseu
   WvW+LPdwbk++SrKo8Df1H5ff5hDZYJ/x+NPDJ/ZmoY7r2U83aGY+DubilufhDf6i
   cB2auTGxBvVylAl5Jdf7UBsjHAWrgWAtFFvnkbcaUk1O7ZA8nS4Iyk4l8vVsoUOJ
   CSRrysceObAOG+EYj1UfdzOBZsuSj5Usst6ebRjF9M1VNJOLcvm6EiAqazayyqbs
   engnA+hqUGRgfd6HXXZ5Hg4BU/srPVBXrVmx81azHY5lRUdZr/Khtw4O0Zy3UIwM
   WwIDAQAB
   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----


   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   MIICHgIBAAKCAQEA0h5Pgw32t3NtODVj1UrNkk90RytZBz2T09JBEo1NwYtw0T7N
   M3SrFsleLK8e/DknE26rB8EXD2T1YmUSuseuWvW+LPdwbk++SrKo8Df1H5ff5hDZ
   YJ/x+NPDJ/ZmoY7r2U83aGY+DubilufhDf6icB2auTGxBvVylAl5Jdf7UBsjHAWr
   gWAtFFvnkbcaUk1O7ZA8nS4Iyk4l8vVsoUOJCSRrysceObAOG+EYj1UfdzOBZsuS
   j5Usst6ebRjF9M1VNJOLcvm6EiAqazayyqbsengnA+hqUGRgfd6HXXZ5Hg4BU/sr
   PVBXrVmx81azHY5lRUdZr/Khtw4O0Zy3UIwMWwIBAAKCAQAeA/pzzEDcP/7wMqBK
   Td9D8Vm4+PZE1IUTk0t8bPcYmOTK31/M4/O005tCYtnYSgnM+tgvyWOT7WYoYivk
   xrWfhM9f+RD0kSur3A3KExRPKRDw+qMy7GZSl12fjdFnbtU+O9S8cy6WTmE8EW/S
   4fcucOwzXGffiJyPjTLjNxFNhfCLGoOCPvhRr/1ppnA9dfTpiRze/MLkzgXkk/hm
   O4tMWOYzyPHMmm7gk0OdxfCEcTle2/e3Wh7NdMc1l1HPJNO0Us57Jh4u3lZYz7Ln
   j127eGxS2+A2cnglNLi4QcSicMxbwJXlnOhATwXzUtPlDzhyhjM6NWXMLnTDuy3e
   8sVhAgEAAgEAAgEAAgEAAgEA
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ```

I am taking these keys and going to `https://jwt.io/` , then updating Header and payload with my required values.
Header:

```
{
 "alg": "RS256",
 "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Payload :

```
        {
      "iss": "e9064e3cb1cc445cb2095f3dc675b4gf",
      "sub": "e9064e3cb1cc445cb2095f3dc675b4gf",
      "aud": [
        "southgate"
      ],
      "iat": 1543469348,
      "nbf": 1543469348,
      "exp": 1543517174,
      "jti": "a6fb0873-8653-4923-be47-e53e0acabb35",
      "schemas": [
        "urn:x:y:v1"
      ],
      "ten": "myTen"
    }
```

After this when I sign the JWT including public and private key from above, It doesnt generate JWT token and gives "INVALID SIGNATURE" error. SO I am not able to generate the signed JWT which is needed as input for this 2nd API.

PS- I am in testing phase now. So I havent wrote any code to test the api and using only online generator tool.

Please let me know how I can solve the issue.